# Azure Virtual Wan Load Balacing

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-load-balancer, wan

We have Azure Virtual Wan Hub and Spoke Design with couple of Vnet Peering on the same Region.

I have 3 Servers and the 3 of them are on different Vnet's but all connected to the Hub (Virtual Wan).

Is the only way to load balance the 3 servers with one VIP is to have a Network Virtual Appliance (NVA) like F5 to do it? I can not find anywhere if the internal load balance would be able to do that, and looks like it does not.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, you may accept it.

Answer (score 1):

After my validation, it's not possible to use [Azure load balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview) to distribute network traffic to the 3 Servers in the same region but on different VNets because All IP configurations in the same backend pool must be on the **same virtual network**. A single backend endpoint pool only can contain resources from one virtual network.

In [Backend pool management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/backend-pool-management), there are two ways of configuring a backend pool:

> - Network Interface Card (NIC)
> - Combination of IP address and Virtual Network (VNET) Resource ID

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nancy, I came with the same outcome. I guess the only way when use hub and spoke (Virtual Wan) would be using F5 (NVA).

Hope it helps someone else out there.